# How to find two elements satisfying two predicates in one pass with Scala?

Tags: scala, collections

Suppose there is a `List[A]` and two predicates `p1: A => Boolean` and `p2: A => Boolean`.
I need to find two elements in the list: the first element `a1` satisfying `p1` and the first element `a2` satisfying `p2` (in my case `a1 != a2`)

Obviously, I can run `find` twice but I would like to do it in *one pass*. How would you do it in one pass in Scala ?

Comment: I bet the resulting code will be way more obscure than two passes. Just saying.

Comment: I guess a tail recursive function will be pretty clear.

Comment: The answer is a fold. The answer is always a fold :) I'll add an answer later when my meeting's over but `myList.foldLeft((None, None)){ case ((a1, a2), e) => (if (!a1.isDefined && p1(e)) Some(e) else a1,if (!a2.isDefined && p2(e)) Some(e) else a2)}` should be close

Comment: @Paul Thank you, but I am afraid that `fold` always iterates through the _whole_ list from the beginning to the end, which is suboptimal. We need to return once the first element are found and skip the rest of the list.

Comment: Ah yes. Back to the drawing board.

Comment: Returned from the drawing board.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, here's an attempt. It's fairly straightforward to generalise it to take a list of predicates (and return a list of elements found)

```
def find2[A](xs: List[A], p1: A => Boolean, p2: A => Boolean): (Option[A], Option[A]) = {
  def find2helper(xs: List[A], p1: A => Boolean, p2: A => Boolean, soFar: (Option[A], Option[A])): (Option[A], Option[A]) = {
    if (xs == Nil) soFar
    else {
      val a1 = if (soFar._1.isDefined) soFar._1 else if (p1(xs.head)) Some(xs.head) else None
      val a2 = if (soFar._2.isDefined) soFar._2 else if (p2(xs.head)) Some(xs.head) else None
      if (a1.isDefined && a2.isDefined) (a1, a2) else find2helper(xs.tail, p1, p2, (a1, a2))
    }
  }
  find2helper(xs, p1, p2, (None, None))

 } //> find2: [A](xs: List[A], p1: A => Boolean, p2: A => Boolean)(Option[A], Option[A])

  val foo = List(1, 2, 3, 4, 5) //> foo  : List[Int] = List(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)

  find2[Int](foo, { x: Int => x > 2 }, { x: Int => x % 2 == 0 })
  //> res0: (Option[Int], Option[Int]) = (Some(3),Some(2))
  find2[Int](foo, { x: Int => x > 2 }, { x: Int => x % 7 == 0 })
  //> res1: (Option[Int], Option[Int]) = (Some(3),None)
  find2[Int](foo, { x: Int => x > 7 }, { x: Int => x % 2 == 0 })
  //> res2: (Option[Int], Option[Int]) = (None,Some(2))
  find2[Int](foo, { x: Int => x > 7 }, { x: Int => x % 7 == 0 })
  //> res3: (Option[Int], Option[Int]) = (None,None)
```

Generalised version (which is actually slightly clearer, I think)

```
def findN[A](xs: List[A], ps: List[A => Boolean]): List[Option[A]] = {
  def findNhelper(xs: List[A], ps: List[A => Boolean], soFar: List[Option[A]]): List[Option[A]] = {
    if (xs == Nil) soFar
    else {
      val as = ps.zip(soFar).map {
          case (p, e) => if (e.isDefined) e else if (p(xs.head)) Some(xs.head) else None
      }
      if (as.forall(_.isDefined)) as else findNhelper(xs.tail, ps, as)
    }
  }
  findNhelper(xs, ps, List.fill(ps.length)(None))

} //> findN: [A](xs: List[A], ps: List[A => Boolean])List[Option[A]]

val foo = List(1, 2, 3, 4, 5) //> foo  : List[Int] = List(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)

findN[Int](foo, List({ x: Int => x > 2 }, { x: Int => x % 2 == 0 }))
//> res0: List[Option[Int]] = List(Some(3), Some(2))
findN[Int](foo, List({ x: Int => x > 2 }, { x: Int => x % 7 == 0 }))
//> res1: List[Option[Int]] = List(Some(3), None)
findN[Int](foo, List({ x: Int => x > 7 }, { x: Int => x % 2 == 0 }))
//> res2: List[Option[Int]] = List(None, Some(2))
findN[Int](foo, List({ x: Int => x > 7 }, { x: Int => x % 7 == 0 }))
//> res3: List[Option[Int]] = List(None, None)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
scala> val l = List(1,2,3)
l: List[Int] = List(1, 2, 3)

scala> val p1 = {x:Int =>  x % 2 == 0}
p1: Int => Boolean = <function1>

scala> val p2 = {x:Int =>  x % 3 == 0}
p2: Int => Boolean = <function1>

scala> val pp = {x:Int => p1(x) || p2(x) }
pp: Int => Boolean = <function1>

scala> l.find(pp)
res2: Option[Int] = Some(2)

scala> l.filter(pp)
res3: List[Int] = List(2, 3)
```

Comment: Thank you. However I don't know which element of the `filtered` list (List(2, 3) in your example) satisfies `p1` and which one satisfies `p2`.

Answer (score 1):

Does this work for you?

```
def predFilter[A](lst: List[A], p1: A => Boolean, p2: A => Boolean): List[A] =
  lst.filter(x => p1(x) || p2(x)) // or p1(x) && p2(x) depending on your need
```

This will return you a new list that matches either of the predicates.

```
val a = List(1,2,3,4,5)
val b = predFilter[Int](a, _ % 2 == 0, _ % 3 == 0) // b is now List(2, 3, 4)
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be p1(x) || p2(x) ?

Comment: @Ashalynd that depends on the use, when I used || `_ > 2` and `_ < 5` matched for the entire list, because ALL the elements are less than 5 except for 5, and 5 is matched by the "greater than two"

Comment: The OP was talking about satisfying either of the predicates.

Comment: @Ashalynd in which case you're right, it should be `||`